# Retain highlighted color of text after editing

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox

Cannot keep the highlighted effect I set in my RichTextBox on my text after removing content of a line in front of him.

No matter how much text I remove from the control it always removes the custom SelectionColor and SelectionBackColor I set to a text already contained in it.

Code of my Removal method:

```
private void btnRemove_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Remove selected line from RichTextBox
    richTextBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text.Remove(richTextBox1.Text.Length - 1, 1);
    //Remove all blank lines remaining after deletion                  
    richTextBox1.Text = Regex.Replace(richTextBox1.Text, @"^\s*$(\n|\r|\r\n)", "", RegexOptions.Multiline);
}
```

The number of letters I want to remove here is 1 as the word "AND" is a simple image inserted by means of Clipboard Paste method.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must never (read my lips: Never, never, never) change to `Text` or the `Lines` property of a `RichtTextBox` or else you will **lose/mess up** all previous formatting.

So you need to change this:

```
richTextBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text.Remove(richTextBox1.Text.Length - 1, 1);
```

To this sequence:

First Select the part of the `Text` you want to change in some way:

```
richTextBox1.SelectionStart = richTextBox1.Text.Length - 1;
richTextBox1.SelectionLength = 1;
```

Now you can change it. To delete either use:

```
richTextBox1.SelectedText = "";
```

or

```
richTextBox1.Cut();
```

The latter version also  will place the text in the clipboard; doing it it will keep the formatting of that portion and you could `Paste` it to some other place..

The same rules apply when you want to add or change any type of formatting:

**First Select Then Modify**

And, yes, this means that the second command will grow quite a bit, i.e. you will have to replace the `RegEx.Replace` by a loop :-(

Comment: You're absolutely right, thank you for the solution and a very good advice on the top of that...